# Java sql getPreparedStatement stopped after 4294967295 rows

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, resultset

I'm trying to fetch all the rows from a table using `java.sql.PreparedStatement` and `executeQuery`, but the download stopped after reaching 4294967295(2^32-1) rows; I've tried `preparedStatement.getMaxRows()` which returns 0, means there's no fetching limit;

according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMaxRows(), "If this limit is exceeded, the excess rows are silently dropped." this sounds exactly what happened to my job, does anyone knows what else should I debug, and why I'm hitting the maximum rows limit when this setting is to 0?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you reading so many rows, in the first place? And out of curiosity, how long did the query take to get there?

Comment: A single query that has to return >4 billion rows smells like a design issue.  Why do you need to return that many rows at once?

Comment: 10 hours, I'm batch downloading data

Comment: Do it in smaller chunks.

Comment: >4 billion rows in one table seems rather large to me

Comment: Yeah, I would get small chunks by some kind of filter/pagination strategy. Timestamp or sequence ids will do. I don't like it when the SQL takes more than a minute to run. It's much safer to figure out a good segmentation strategy, and run a myriad of small (1-minute) queries.

Comment: I'd report this to Oracle.  Sounds like the kind of bug where someone's used an `int` instead of a `long`.

Comment: How do you know it quits after 2^32-1?  What are you doing with the rows?

Comment: All the files downloaded add up to 2^32-1, and no error, the job just stopped, I'm moving the data to another place

Comment: ^ just start again from that point so :)

Comment: Agreed on doing this by smaller chunks, we are in the middle of transferring to distributed downloading, that will take some time to set up the system.

Comment: start again from that point is the plan, I'm trying to see if anyone knows why this would stop when the limit is set to 0; and will work on the alternatives

Comment: Have you checked limitations of your RDBS?

Comment: It’s sql server, and I did some research and rule out the possibility but can look again

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, according to https://www.exasol.com/support/browse/SOL-108

Beware: If you do single loads with more than 4,294,967,295 rows, you should use the MSSQL native JDBC driver due to a bug in JTDS (note that the number 4,294,967,295 is the maximum value for a 32-bit unsigned integer). If you used JTDS for such big loads, only 4,294,967,295 rows would be imported, and the rest would be ignored without seeing an error.

MSSQL JDBC driver and example is here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/java/rhel/step/2.html